# Where are GCP VM startup and shutdown scripts copied to?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm creating GCP VM instances via Terraform, with startup and shutdown scripts supplied via metadata.  I can tell the startup script works, but the shutdown script does not run when `terraform apply` requires the instance to be destroyed.

I'd like to check that the shutdown-script was actually copied to the server, and also be able check the content of both startup and shutdown scripts if I need to debug the templates.

On AWS, they're copied to /var/lib/cloud/instance but under the same location on my GCP VMs, I don't see my scripts there.  Are there other locations I should search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute Engine Shutdown scripts are not guaranteed to run.

> Compute Engine executes shutdown scripts only on a best-effort basis.
> In rare cases, Compute Engine cannot guarantee that the shutdown
> script will complete.

[Shutdown Script Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript#limitations)

You can manually execute a shutdown script to verify/debug execution:

```
google_metadata_script_runner shutdown
```

Startup and Shutdown scripts are stored in metadata. The metadata might indicate that the startup script is located at a URL (e.g. Cloud Storage). The metadata is copied to a local file for execution. The filename is not documented.

Tip: Connect via the instance's serial port and you can watch the shutdown GCEMetadataScripts event start the shutdown script and see the result while it executes.

Comment: Ok, this helps verify there is at least a script... but where is the script on disk, if I wanted to verify the contents?  Or is it not on disk in text format, and copied to the server into a binary?

Comment: @RCross The location is not documented. Also, I think the shutdown script file is created at event time and not in advance. However, I might be wrong. Connect to the serial port and watch. Then shutdown the instance.

Comment: incidentally, the above command threw an error... I had to run ```google_metadata_script_runner shutdown```

Comment: @RCross - Thank you. I updated my answer. I was using the older command syntax.

Comment: @RCross  If you find that provided answer is helpful for your issue, Kindly accept the Answer